# can i narrow the input down but a class

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
    $("input:radio").change(function() {
```

can i do something like

```
    $(".someclass input:radio").change(function() {
```

Is that even correct and if not is there a better way

Answer (score 4):

That'll match a radio input contained in an element with the class "someclass". Yes, it's valid, but without seeing your HTML I don't know if it's "correct".

You can give your radio button an ID and reference it with `#id` if you think that's "better".

Answer (score 1):

the class goes in place of the element type for most uses, it sounds like you want:

```
$(".someclass:radio")
```

note:  `$(":radio")` works fine by it self

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is select all radio buttons that have a certain class, which can be accomplished like this:

```
$("input:radio.someclass").change(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jQuery (I prefer plain old JavaScript), but you could use getElementsByClassName('someclass') then check them to make sure they're an input of type radio.

Comment: Why create more work for yourself when jQuery does all that for you? Maybe if you're only querying one element... but in general, it's a time-saver.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is only supported on IE9+, so it's not going to be of much use in say... oh, the next 10 years